# JaxB xjc generated pojos contains blank namespaces

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I'm using xjc from the command line to generate POJOs from an XSD. Here's the command I run:

```
"%java_home%\bin\xjc" -p com.etc.etc.etc.etc ConsolidatedAlert.xsd
```

For some of the POJOs generated, the properties in the POJO come back like the following:

```
@XmlElement(name = "UnparsedTelephone", namespace="")
protected String unparsedTelephone;
```

As far as I can tell, I don't specify these elements any differently than others that don't have the "namespace" attribute.

Here's the relevant sections of the XSD:

Type declaration:

```
<xs:complexType name="TelephoneType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="UnparsedTelephone" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="ParsedTelephone" type="ParsedTelephoneType"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Element declaration:

```
<xs:element name="Telephone" type="TelephoneType"/>
```

Where "Telephone" is used:

```
<xs:complexType name="CompanyContactType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Telephone"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Where "CompanyContact" is used:

```
<xs:complexType name="AmountType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="CompanyContact" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="TriggerAmount" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I can simply remove the namespace="" from each POJO, but that can take a bit, and I'd like a better understanding about why it's happening in the first place.

Also, this is about 8 XSDs all linked together. They all have the same targetNamespace and xmlns in the schema definition, but some of them have elementFormDefault="unqualified" and others have elementFormDefault="qualified". Could this be the cause of the problem?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Namespace Qualification & XML Schema

When `elementFormDefault="qualified"` all the elements corresponding to this XML Schema will be namespace qualified.  When `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` only global (top level) elements will be namespace qualified.

### Namespace Qualification & JAXB

JAXB allows the namespace qualification to be set at the package level using `@XmlSchema`.  Since you have multiple schemas and an undisclosed number of generated packages it's very possible XJC generated `""` for namespace to override the default qualification to match the schema rules.

Comment: Simple as that! Changed the few schemas that had "unqualified" to "qualified" and that did the trick! Now I'm wondering in what situation you'd use "unqualified".